# Which web programming frameworks can generate CRUD interface dynamically in runtime?

Tags: scaffolding

I mean a tool like [**dynamic** scaffolding in Grails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hVXw2DoI_8). I do not write about static scaffolding which stores View files on disk drive since I would like to avoid it. Moreover I don't take Ruby on Rails into account because dynamic scaffolding in RoR was deprecated.

More than 10 years ago I wrote a fully functional application using a PHP framework generating CRUD interface dynamically. For each database table I had to:

- give a SQL query reading a list of rows that were later displayed on a web page in an automatically generated, paginated, orderable and searchable browser,
- give a list of fields to display together with their types and labels (and optionally with their initial values displayed on Create pages),
- give titles of CRUD pages,
- implement functions other than CRUD.

It was easy to build a complete application using this framework and the application was fully functional so I know that even dynamically generated views can be used in production. Unfortunately the framework was not an open source.

Comment: this might be of interest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DF93WU2wTEI

Comment: [PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net)? :P

Comment: One can check also [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Dynamic_Data) - [ASP.NET Dynamic Data Introduction](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/).